# Qt Style QRadioButton label?

Tags: python, pyqt, qradiobutton

Is there a way to style QRadioButton labels? specifically I want to movethe label to the top, from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

The latter having been done in tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using `QVBoxLayout` and `QLabel` within a `QHBoxLayout`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QLabel, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,
    QApplication, QWidget
)
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.vlayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label1 = QLabel("HW")
        self.radiobutton1 = QRadioButton()
        self.radiobutton1.setChecked(True)
        self.radiobutton1.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.vlayout1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.vlayout1.addWidget(self.radiobutton1)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.vlayout1)

        self.vlayout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label2 = QLabel("SW")
        self.radiobutton2 = QRadioButton()
        self.radiobutton2.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.vlayout2.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.vlayout2.addWidget(self.radiobutton2)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.vlayout2)

    def onClicked(self):
        radioButton = self.sender()
        if radioButton.isChecked():
            print("Radio button clicked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Forgive me for being picky but I originally didn't go with this because even though there is no label attached to the radio buttons, you can see that they still allocate a margin for it to be there, causing everything to be off-center. Completely re-positioning this margin could fix that but also a styling fix to eliminate it could as well. IIRC a negative right margin didn't work for this.

Comment: It's okay, @Laif. I would consider using  [addStretch](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) and/or [addSpacerItem](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addSpacerItem).

Comment: How would those help?

Comment: @Laif Using `addStretch` will push the radio-button up against the label. To centre the widgets, do `layout.addWidget(widget, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter)`. The gap between the label and the button can be adjusted with `layout.setSpacing(num)`.

Comment: I am talking about the space to the _right_ of the actual button. It causes the indicator to stick out of the left side of the label. The distance between the label and the indicator is fine.

Comment: @Laif Give the button a fixed width, so it doesn't expand horizontally: `button.setFixedWidth(button.sizeHint().height())`.

Comment: @ekhumoro This causes strange clipping issues as well as making the container extra wide.

Comment: @Laif Works fine for me. When I make the suggested changes to the example code shown above, it looks exactly like the second image shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information, @ekhumoro. :)